# Tests started failing with Timed out waiting for asynchronous Angular tasks to finish reason

Tags: angularjs, protractor

Some how my tests started failing with the reason "Timed out waiting for asynchronous Angular tasks to finish reason". The same tests that were running perfectly before. I assure that there are no code changes. 
I have a wait time of 50 secs( 
  allScriptsTimeout: 50000,
  getPageTimeout: 50000,). Mine is an angular application and i dont want to use browser.ignoresynchronization.
I use jasmine version 2.8.0.

Code follows :

logout.page:

```
get el() {
return $('userbarforlogout');
}

get menu() {
return $('dropdown');
}

get logoutLink() {
return this.menu.$('logout');
}

async logout() {
await this.el.click();
await this.logoutLink.click();
}
```

spec file :

```
describe('logout action', function() {

it('should logout', async function() {
let ac1 = new logout();
await ac1.logout();
}); 
});
```

Any suggestions are really appreciated?

Thanks

Comment: Please add your codes.

Comment: Yes i have added the code now. Thanks

Comment: `ignoreSynchronization` is officially deprecated. Instead there is `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false)`. As you're using `async/await` you can't avoid to switch off the Protractor Control Flow Mgmt, because native promises and protractor/selenium promises create a mess together. Check the async/await-description on www.protractortest.org

Comment: @ErnstZwingi , thank you much for your response. But i dont understand what actually went wrong with my code. It started failing suddenly. I seriously dont see any new changes being made to the application.

Comment: @ErnstZwingli , Having said that , setting browser.waitForAngularEnabled to false is not helping either.

Comment: "I assure that there are no code changes" -- does that mean you are the only person building this application?  If they started failing randomly, I suspect something has changed

Comment: @Gunderson , No i am not the only one developing .. but we have a CI environment and these tests run against every build. I was so confident about code changes because there were no commits when the tests started failing. I  saw a similar issue logged on GitHub , where the tests failing for the same reason. Its because of the timeouts. I am sure protractor should be designed to handle these timeouts.  For now , my dev team is working to run the application timeouts outside angular. But i am sure there should be a way for the protractor team to handle this situation.